# Trying to get data from barcode device

Tags: java, android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a barcode device that can be connected to a computer or to an android device through USB port.
It scans the barcode and show the result wherever it finds a cursor, it can be an editbox, notepad, browser or whatever.
What I want to do is to get data in a variable as soon it scans the barcode without showing it on the edittext.

Comment: Perhaps you could give focus to a 'hidden' `EditText` when you're about to scan a barcode? That way the result doesn't show upon being returned and you can attach a simple `TextWatcher` to the hidden `EditText` to store the result in a variable. Just not sure whether you can actually focus a view that isn't visible...

Comment: Can you provide us with the model of scanner that you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scanner is functionally equivalent to a keyboard, so you can't scan the data directly into a variable.

However, as @MH. suggested, you can watch a text input field and grab the data once it's entered. You might be able to programmaticly set the focus on the hidden field when the user clicks a button. If that doesn't work you might be able to style the input so the user can't see the scanned data (eg make the text color the same as the background color)